# Print the height of binary tree separately

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

```
int height(struct node* node) 
{ 
    /* base case tree is empty */
    if (node == NULL) 
        return 0; 
  
    /* If tree is not empty then height = 1 + max of left 
      height and right heights */
    return 1 + max(height(node->left), height(node->right)); 
}
```

Above is very basic code to find the height of binary Tree. But I am not able to print the **left and right height separately** in the calling function . I tried by passing the call by reference too, but I got unexpected results.

**Problem Statement:** find the height of binary search tree where a tree with 1 node will be considered as height 0, and a tree with no node will be considered as height -1.

**Expected Output:**
left height :1, right height: 3 (Cat is the root node)

```
          cat
         /    \
      bear     dog
     /         /   \
 alligator   dear   tiger
             /       /
            cow    lion
                   /
                 horse
```

This code has to be written in the **C language**. Is this method correct to find the height?

Following output generated to cross verify tree by inorder traversal

```
 node:alligator 
 node:bear   bear:->left  alligator
 node:cat    cat:->left  bear     cat:->right dog
 node:cow 
 node:deer   deer:->left  cow
 node:dog    dog:->left  deer     dog:->right tiger
 horse 
 lion   lion:->left  horse
 tiger      tiger:->left  lion
```

Comment: why expected left height is `1` , per definition it is to be `2`? and when node is 'null' height is `-1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the left and right height separately, find it out separately:

```
int  left_height = height( root->left) - 1;
int right_height = height(root->right) - 1;
```

Comment: I tried this way too , but it shows the same value for entire tree. shows 5 ,5 for both tree..

Comment: @johnbyro Then the issue is elsewhere, this code is fine.

Comment: please read the problem statement . It is not as usual , it returns -1 if no node present , and 1 if one node present . I am not able to interpret this info,

Comment: @johnbyro Excuse me? I read your question, please don't assume I didn't. You said for a single node the result should be `0`, hence the `-1`. Your issue lies in the other code, not this code.

Comment: I agree with you , i have upadted the question with the cross output of inorder traversal , it shows correctly built tree

Answer (score 0):

Calling `printf("%d", height(root->left))` and `printf("%d", height(root->right))` on your root node should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper function for your `height` function:

```
void printHeight(struct node* root)
{
    int leftHeight = (root==nullptr) ? 0 : height(root->left);
    int rightHeight = (root==nullptr) ? 0 : height(root->right);

    printf("left height: %d, right height: %d", leftHeight-1, rightHeight-1);
}
```

Comment: did not worked .. Is the method height() is correct which has been provided in the code??

Comment: Updated to do the `-1` thing that I had hoped you would have identified yourself as an easy bug fix.

Comment: did not work i mean , it is not printing the correct height as expected in the problem statement . However , when i do the inorder traversal , it shows tree is build correctly as expected